# Python pip: cloudmonkey not installing correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install Cloudmonkey on a VM. I downloaded cloudmonkey and tried to run the following command "pip install cloudmonkey" and get the following error:

Collecting cloudmonkey
  Using cached cloudmonkey-5.3.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-gx5p5q5b\cloudmonkey\setup.py", line 50
        print "If you're upgrading, run the following to enable parameter completion:"
                                                                                     ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build
oudmonkey

Would someone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong with this install?

Answer (score 1):

In source code, line 50 to 53 have four print statements without parenthesis in their [setup.py](https://github.com/apache/cloudstack-cloudmonkey/blob/master/setup.py). That is not compatible with python 3.x

It looks like from version 5.2 to 5.3, they added the print statements as upgrade notes. I recommend looking if there is an issue for compatibility, or you can download from source, remove those print statements, and then build/install.

Also, they have a docker image in github if you want to try that as well.

I just installed it using python 2.x and it was successful.

Comment: Thanks for your response, did you install anything else or change for the configuration for Python 2.x?

Comment: Nothing extra, just python 2.x, pip, setuptools and cloudmonkey.

Comment: I tried to run "cloudmonkey" and I received this error message now --------


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\cloudmonkey.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cloudmonkey\cloudmonkey.py", line 70, in <
module>
    if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable